# Validate whether output file generated for each device in a file name

Tags: python, loops, validation

I have a sample.txt file that contains 3 (example) device details, and in python function, I'm iterating through each device and creating a report file out of it.

Once the report file generates for all the devices then only the next transformation should start. So, what is the best way to validate whether a report file is generated for each device in a file or not?

```
sample.txt
{
  "ID": "11",
  
  "device_details": [
    {
      "name": "A1",
      "IP": "94.159.102.125"
    },
    {
      "name": "A2",
      "IP": "94.159.102.125"
    },
    {
      "name": "A3",
      "IP": "94.159.102.125"
    }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```py
class A:
    def func1(self):
        path = "/sample.txt"
        if os.path.exists(path):
            self.file = json.loads(open(path).read())
            for device in self.file["device_details"]:
                pool = Pool(processes=1)
                pool.apply_async(B.func2(device)) ##This calls asynchronously and generates report file
    
    @classmethod
    def func3(self,listofdevice):
        outputdirectory = "/report/"
        for eachHost in listofdevice:  #####["A1","A2","A3"]
            OReportname = outputdirectory + "/" + self.eachHost + "_report.txt"
            if (os.path.exists(OReportname)):
                for r in glob.glob(outputdirectory + "/" + "*_report.txt"):
                    with open(r) as repfile:
                        old_data = repfile.read()
                        report.append(json.load(old_data))
```

Currently, the code is looking for report.txt extension in the folder and consolidate the file contents of all available report.txt into one file.
But before consolidating I have to validate whether the report.txt file created for each device or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a code template for what you're trying to do. Note that:

- I'm using a single pool for all the sub-processes. That's the intention of a pool.
- I'm waiting for the results of this pool to know what succeeded and what failed.
- Each sub-process returns a success / failure status.

```
import os
import json 
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random 
import time 


class A:
    def func1(self):
        # read the file ... 
        self.file = json.loads(text)
        self.devices = self.file["device_details"]

        with Pool() as pool: 
            results = pool.map_async(A.func2, self.devices) ##This calls asynchronously and generates report file
            print("Started processes")
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            print("Results are:", results.get())
            if not all(results.get()):
                print("At least one job failed")
    
    @classmethod
    def func2(self, device):
        print(f"Simulating some work for device {device}")
        time.sleep(random.random() * 2)
        print(f"Done simulating some work for device {device}")
        device_name = device["name"]
        res_value = f"dummy_file.{device_name}.txt"
        return res_value

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    a.func1()
```

The output of this code is:

```
Started processes
Simulating some work for device {'name': 'A1', 'IP': '94.159.102.125'}
Simulating some work for device {'name': 'A2', 'IP': '94.159.102.125'}
Simulating some work for device {'name': 'A3', 'IP': '94.159.102.125'}
Done simulating some work for device {'name': 'A2', 'IP': '94.159.102.125'}
Done simulating some work for device {'name': 'A1', 'IP': '94.159.102.125'}
Done simulating some work for device {'name': 'A3', 'IP': '94.159.102.125'}
Results are: ['dummy_file.A1.txt', 'dummy_file.A2.txt', 'dummy_file.A3.txt']
```

Note the last line: it's printed by the calling function and contains the results (return value) of all the child processes.

Comment: Thanks, @Roy2012 for your response. Here, what are we expecting in results.get()? because when func2 runs asynchronously in return 'results' variable won't carry any actual report file details. I'm getting Nonetype in results.get(). Error:TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Once func2 is done, results.get returns a list of the return values from the N calls to this function. In my case, they are all true. But - you can return something else.

Comment: Thank you much for your time.